# How to add alphabets without space validation in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, form-validation

There are `validate-alpha` and `validate-alphanum-with-spaces` classes in magento form validation .

But how to do only  `validate-alpha-with-spaces` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference: [Magento validation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700464/magento-validation-class)

You can create you own custom validation class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
Validation.add('validate-alpha-spac','You failed to enter baz!',function(v)        {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
});  
</script>
```

See http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation

or

```
  Validation.addAllThese([
      'validate-alpha-space', 
      'Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.', 
      function (v) { return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
 }]),
```

see http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/custom-javascript-form-validators

Comment: Its another idea to include spaces also in validation.js "validate-alpha" method .